# Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'epharmacy.medicines' doesn't exist

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I am trying to build a table but when i run this command " php artisan migrate " this error is occured:

[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'epharmacy.medici
  nes' doesn't exist (SQL: alter table `medicines` add `id` int unsigned not
  null auto_increment primary key, add `name` varchar(255) not null, add `typ

  e` varchar(255) not null, add `potency` varchar(255) not null, add `created

  _at` timestamp null, add `updated_at` timestamp null)

Migration:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateMedicineTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('medicines', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->String('name');
            $table->String('type');
            $table->String('potency');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('medicines', function (Blueprint $table) {
            //
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: change class name createmedicinetable to criatemedicines table and try

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/schema#creating-and-dropping-tables), it needs to be:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateMedicineTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('medicines', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('type');
            $table->string('potency');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('medicines');
    }
```

}